# Python FLASHTEXT returns only last Key in case of duplicate - I need to find all matching cases

Tags: python, regex

I'm running the below code but want to get all possible clean-words where there is match present.
For example if I pass the value of PM which has 2 clean-words (Project & Product Management), i should get both as output and not just the last one.

```
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor
keyword_processor = KeywordProcessor(case_sensitive = False)
keyword_dict = {
     "java": ["java_2e", "java programing"],
     "project management": ["PM", "project manager"],
     "product management": ["PM", "product manager"]
 }

# {'clean_name': ['list of unclean names']}
keyword_processor.add_keywords_from_dict(keyword_dict)
# Or add keywords from a list:
#keyword_processor.add_keywords_from_list(["java", "python"])
print(keyword_processor.extract_keywords('I am a PM for a java_2e platform', span_info=True))
# output ['product management', 'java']
```

The above implementation only returns the last match (in this case if PM is searched then only PRODUCT MANAGEMENT comes and not PROJECT MANAGEMENT).

IS there a way to get both as part of the result ?

Comment: Sounds like PM is a hash key, so only the last assigned value, etc..

Comment: yes, i just ran a get_all_keyword again it and it returns this :
{'java_2e': 'java', 'java programing': 'java', 'pm': 'product management', 'project manager': 'project management', 'product manager': 'product management'}.
is there a way to get all instances ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor
keyword_processor = KeywordProcessor(case_sensitive = False)
keyword_dict = {
     "java": ["java_2e", "java programing"],
     "project management": ["project manager"],
     "product management": ["product manager"]
 }

keyword_processor.add_keywords_from_dict(keyword_dict)
keyword_processor.add_keyword('PM', ["project management", 'product management'])
print(keyword_processor.extract_keywords('I am a PM for a java_2e platform', span_info=True))
# output [(['project management', 'product management'], 7, 9), ('java', 16, 23)]
```

Comment: Thanks, 
If the dictionary which is predefined with PM being a sub-context for 2 keywords (as in the example i gave) is not changed, is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: There is no other way